# How to sum values in excel on 1st of each month for the previous month excel

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

[image]

Already tried SUMIF AND SUMIFS and SUMproduct doesn't work properly

I need to have the sum of all savings in amt paid 1st Feb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(INT(A2)=EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1,SUMIFS($C$2:C2,$A$2:A2,">="&EOMONTH(A2,-2)+1,$A$2:A2,"<"&EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

=IF(INT(A2)=EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1,SUMIFS($C$2:C2,$A$2:A2,">="&EOMONTH(A2,-2)+1,$A$2:A2,"<"&EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1),0)

thanks to @ Scott Craner